# dynamic scope values angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

I have multiple routes which serves different pages like so:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/routeone', {
        templateUrl: '/routes/one',
        resolve: {}
    })
    .when('/routetwo', {
        templateUrl: '/routes/two',
        controller: 'CampaignController',
        resolve: {

        }
    })
    .when('/routethree', {
        templateUrl: '/routes/three',
        resolve: {}
    });
```

Each route page has different model fields but uses one single $scope variable i.e. $scope.template so in one route/template it is:

```
<span>{{template.var1}}</span>
```

on other it is

```
<span>{{template.var2}}</span>
```

I am fetching route specific data and storing it in $scope.template, but the issue is even when it is assigned it is not showing it on UI fields which are bound.. initially my $scope.template is set to empty string.

If i set all the fields that are used in all the route template like

```
$scope.template = { var1 = 'var1', var2='var2'}
```

it works which i don't want to do but if i set it to empty and fetch route specific on route change it doesn't.. can someone plz help..

here is the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FzOrU3Z5bSGot1YAvVCj?p=preview)

Comment: can you please add a plunker !!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in your plunker?

Comment: on route change success when i use $http instead of directly assigning the template field it doesn't bind even when it has the updated data from service call

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: no, i am updating the $scope.template from db with hundreds of properties like var1, var2, and so on.. and these properties vary from route/template..

Comment: bcos http calls are asynchronous calls...i think this is the problem you are facing..

Comment: no wait, sync calls written on $routeChangeSuccess works like a charm.. i was previously callling it in $routeChangeStart.. thanks for the hint